# How to show all rows from database using Hibernate MySQL Maven Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I want to show all rows from table bank. Currently my code can only show selected rows only. This code that i make is following https://mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/ tutorial

here's my main class

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext appContext=
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");
        BankBo bankBo =(BankBo)appContext.getBean("bankBo");

        System.out.println("||  CODE   ||    NAME    ||  ALIAS  ||");
        /*select*/
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++) {
        Bank bank = bankBo.findByBankCode("002");
        System.out.println(bank);}    
    }
}
```

DaoImpl

```
public class BankDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements BankDao {

    public Bank findByBankCode(String bankCode){
        List<?> list = getHibernateTemplate().find(
                " from Bank where bankCode=?", bankCode);
        return (Bank)list.get(0);

    }
}
```

The rest of the code is almost the same from the tutorial. I only edited Insert,Update, and Delete only. Cause i only want to show data only

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved it. It was pretty simple actually.

DaoImpl

```
@Override
    public List<Bank> listBank() {
        List<Bank> list = getHibernateTemplate().find(
              " from Bank");
    return list;
    }
```

and the main class will be

```
System.out.println("||  CODE   ||    NAME    ||  ALIAS  ||");
        /*select*/
        List<Bank> list = bankBo.listBank();
        for(Bank bank1:list) {
            System.out.println(bank1.toString());
        }
```